# generate a pdf in C# winforms application

Tags: pdf, c#, pdf-generation

I have a pdf report that I should generate in my WinForms application. The pdf report will include multiple images and a watermark and signatures and a lot of fields. I read about the libraries and references I can use like:

- ITextSharp
- PdfSharp

But I am wondering if there is another way to design some sort of document that can work as a template so that I can only pass the variable fields to and generate it as a pdf, or there is no other way and I should create my pdf from zero to hero?

Comment: It appears you want to simplify creating the PDF from the reports. If you have a way of creating the report in any format, such as Doc file, HTML or even Windows Metafile, you could use the [LEADTOOLS Document Converter SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) to convert the generated report to PDF after your code creates it. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor.) If you'd like to try the SDK, there's a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

You can use three solutions to create a PDF document with a personalized template.

The first option involves designing an HTML template with the required fields, merging your actual data into it, and then converting it to a PDF using the steps described in this link: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/generate-dynamic-pdf-reports-from-html-template-using-csharp.aspx.

The second solution involves creating a Word document template with the desired layout, formatting, graphics, and fields using Microsoft Word, and then populating it with your data before converting it to a PDF using the Syncfusion .NET Word (DocIO) Library. For more information on this option, check out these links:

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/pdf-creation-document-processing-libraries.aspx#create-a-pdf-file-from-a-word-template.

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/mail-merge-word-csharp-ultimate-guide.aspx

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-mail-merge

Finally, Using the Syncfusion PDF library, it is possible to create and populate PDF forms, including various form fields like text boxes, labels, check boxes, and signatures. You can start from scratch, design a PDF document with the desired form fields, and then later load and fill it with real data. For more information on creating and filling form fields, please refer to the following links:

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms#creating-a-new-pdf-form

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms#filling-form-fields-in-an-existing-pdf-document

[https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf-framework/net](https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf-framework/net%C2%A0)

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion